# Updating and Transitioning Individual SVG Elements Within a Group in D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I currently have a series of rectangles that I would like to change the fill colours individually.

[image: start]

I have tried updating the fill colour using a loop but the whole set of rectangles updates the fill colour at the same time.

[image: result]

Therefore, I tried adding a delay, there is a delay but then the fill colour changes to orange together for all rectangles. I have also tried the setTimeout method in Javascript but the same thing happens.

I would like to be able to see the changes happening one by one, i.e the fill for "a" changes, pause, "f" fill changes, pause, and so on. How would I be able to do this?

Also, is there a way (within a loop) to change the individual rectangle fills? Like the image below, when the variable i in the loop is equal to 4, g's fill changes colour, however once i is equal to 5, I'd like to change g back to blue and y to orange. Is there a way to do this without having to creating two d3 methods, one to update the colour to orange and then update i-1th element back to having a blue fill again?

[image: ideal]

Code used so far to update the fill colour, at the moment updates everything all at once.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++ ) {
                svg.select("#rect" + i)
                   .data([i])   
                   .transition()
                   .delay(1000)
                   .attr("x", (i * 45) + 45)
                   .attr("y", "0px")
                   .attr("width", "40px")
                   .attr("height", "40px")
                   .attr("fill", "rgb(255, 116, 56)");                             
            }
```

I should also add that each rectangle has its own ID, i.e. "a" has ID rect0 and "f" is rect1, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the delay a function of `i`.  Like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967) (and many others).

```
rect.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * 10; }) 
      .attr(/* Change something */);
```

The first element starts changing immediately, the second one 10 milliseconds later, and so on.